# Javascript hitting rails3 route claims it needs authentication, even though I'm already logged in

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, basic-authentication

I have a rails 3 app, where one of the pages has some javascript stuff (an OpenLayers map) that hits a route that requires authentication. When I hit the route, I get an http basic auth pop up that makes me log in. However, I'm already logged into the page, and would figure that this would be saved.  It's a little annoying to have to log in twice.  Once I've logged in once to the javascript stuff, I don't have to log in again...but why do I even have to do it once?

Edit:

To clarify, what is happening is:

1. I log into the rails application with Devise.
2. I do a variety of admin things on rails, succesfully.
3. I go to the page that has the OpenLayers map, and draw on the map, which causes javascript to do a GET on a rails route that is admin only.
4. I get a javascript popup asking me to log in.
5. I log in, and the javascript works as expected.
6. If I navigate away from this page and come back later (as long as I don't clear out my browser cache) I can do the javascript admin stuff all day without having to log in again.

My confusion is that I don't think I should get that javascript pop up in the first place... Does the rails app and javascript keep separate session/cookie data?  I thought Devise itself just did things by IP? (and thus would see javascript and native rails as identical?)

Comment: What authentication are you using?

Comment: Devise, just the basic set up.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it's a GET rather than POST? What happens if you disable the Basic Auth in devise? config.http_authenticatable = false

Comment: When you look at your production.log, is the javascript request of the same origin? If so, try to output some session information from within your controller in order to see the difference. Does a self-made ajax request to the route work without re-authentication?